# Get storage location and storage format for a table in Hive using JDBC?

Tags: sql, jdbc, hive

I want to get the metadata ( including storage format and storage location) of a table in Hive using JDBC. I tried searching but could not find anything related to that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this code example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBCClientSampleCode)
You can send a `describe formatted <tableName>` statement to the server, as you would send any other `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Any clean way to get the partition column information ?

Comment: You can send `describe formatted <tableName>.<columnName>` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way is to use **hcatalog** in this case.

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive.hcatalog</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-webhcat-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Sample code:

```
HiveConf hcatConf = new HiveConf();

hcatConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, connectionUri);
hcatConf.set("hive.metastore.local", "false");

HCatClient client = null;
HCatTable hTable = null;

try {
    client = HCatClient.create(hcatConf);
    hTable = client.getTable(databaseName, tableName);
    System.out.println(hTable.getLocation());
    System.out.println(hTable.getInputFileFormat());
    System.out.println(hTable.getOutputFileFormat());

} catch (HCatException hCatEx) {
    LOG.error("Not able to connect to hive. Caused By;", hCatEx);
}
```

Check other methods of [**HCatTable**](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/hcatalog/webhcat/java-client/org/apache/hcatalog/api/HCatTable.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I would not be able to use HCat for my use case.